# How make a scrollable div scroll with the mouse over the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwOyQo

Friends, is there any way to make this div scroll even being with the mouse over the boxes??

Html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="container-scroll">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="list-item one"></li>
                <li class="list-item two"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: scroll;
        color: white;
    }
    .container-scroll {
        width: 100%;
        height: 4000px;
    }
    .list {
        list-style: none;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .list-item {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .list-item.one {
        background: pink;
    }
.list-item.two{
        background: black;
  float: right;
    }
```

I was trying to make something with overflow but anything worked..

Comment: can you explain how you want it to scroll and what do you mean by mouse over the content?

Comment: the container is scrollable , but when I put the mouse over the boxes and try scroll , nothing happens. I would like to scroll the container when the mouse is on top of the boxes too, you know?

Comment: I added an answer that does what you want using CSS

Answer (score 0):

You've set those elements to `position: fixed`. This positions the elements relative to the *browser*, which means they're completely taken out of the flow of their parent. So of course, when you hover over them, the container won't scroll.

You could use `pointer-events: none` on those boxes, but this isn't supported well across all browsers. Also, it's unclear whether you might actually need pointer events inside those elements in the future.

My advice would be to remove the scrollable div. Ensure that the body/document is the only element that scrolls. That way the content will scroll no matter what element you're currently mousing over.

Comment: so is impossible do what i want?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari I'd say so, but someone might come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

This will do the trick

**EXAMPLE**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPKOog